# DevExpress CardView.CardCaptionFormat Issues

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to make the `CardView1.CardCaptionFormat` entry specific, eg - Show the name and surname of each specific person as the caption for each card.

The code works somewhat, but it displays the LAST entry's name and surname as the caption for each card.

Here is the code:

```
foreach (DataRow x in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    strNameSurname = x[0].ToString() + " " + x[1].ToString();
    cardView1.CardCaptionFormat = x[0].ToString() + " " + x[1].ToString();
}

//x[0] is the name of an individual, x[1] is the surname of an individual.
```

I hope this is clear enough for everyone to understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Niranjan-Kala. This link you posted helped me. Here's the link for future reference: [CodeHelp](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ46851.aspx)

Here's my code fix:
`cardView1.CardCaptionFormat = "{" + cardView1.Columns[0].AbsoluteIndex + 1 + "}"`

Granted, it only shows the names so far, but adding the surnames in there won't be too much of an effort.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following Remarks on [CardView.CardCaptionFormat Property](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsCardCardView_CardCaptionFormattopic) documentatopm"

> The CardCaptionFormat property enables you to construct a caption text
>   using static text together with the current record number and column
>   values. The '{0}' character sequence is a placeholder for the current
>   record number. Thus, the default property value specifies that card
>   captions should contain 'Record N ' followed by the card number. To
>   display column values within card captions, you need to use the
>   desired column indexes. For instance, a '{1}' character sequence is a
>   placeholder for the first column value, etc.

If your table is bound to the grid then you can assign the column index of `Name` and `Surname` columns in the format string then it will automatically reflect the caption as per your requirement.

Assuming that your name and  surname column index is 0 and 1 respectively.. then your *CardView.CardCaptionFormat* Property will be set as  below:

```
CardView.CardCaptionFormat = {0} + "" + {1}
```

Source: [CardCaptionFormat](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/DQ46851.aspx)
To show a custom card caption you should handle the `CardView.CustomDrawCardCaption` event and explicitly set the `CardInfo.CaptionInfo.CardCaption` property. I have prepared an example for you. It is in the attachment. The essential code follows:

```
Private Sub CardView1_CustomDrawCardCaption(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Card.CardCaptionCustomDrawEventArgs) Handles CardView1.CustomDrawCardCaption
    Dim view As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Card.CardView = sender
    Dim s As String = String.Format("Subject: {0}", view.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, "ProductName"))
    CType(e.CardInfo, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Card.ViewInfo.CardInfo).CaptionInfo.CardCaption = s
End Sub
```

For More Reference:
[How to set different CardCaptionFormat for multiple cards](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q206320.aspx)
[Card Caption](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument524)